# How to apply a meta function to the template types of a variadic template class?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Lets assume I have numerous atomic structs each having an `inner_type`:

```
struct Atomic1{
    using inner_type = int;
};
struct Atomic2{
    using inner_type = double;
};
struct Atomic3{
    using inner_type = bool;
};
...
```

My client class is a variadic template that can use 1 or more of the above  atomic classes:

```
template<class ...AtomicTypeArgPack>
class MyclassAcceptingAtomicTypes;
```

I have have a related generic class that accepts `Atomic*::inner_type` as template parameters:

```
template<class ...InnerTypeArgPack>
class MyclassAcceptingInnerTypes;
```

My specific api class is defined but specifying a couple of template types:

```
using my_first_class_t = MyclassAcceptingAtomicTypes<Atomic1, Atomic2>;
```

for each specific class, I also have another class of inner types:

```
using my_first_class_inner_types_t = MyclassAcceptingInnerTypes<Atomic1::inner_type ,  Atomic2::inner_type >;
```

Is there is way to automatically generate the second type (i.e. `my_first_class_inner_types_t`) from the first declaration (`my_first_class_t`) using template meta programming / meta functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is way to automatically generate the second type (i.e. `my_first_class_inner_types_t`) from the first declaration (`my_first_class_t`) using template meta programming / meta functions?

Do you mean something as follows ?

```
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto foo (MyclassAcceptingAtomicTypes<Ts...> const &)
   -> MyclassAcceptingInnerTypes<typename Ts::inner_type...>;

template <typename T>
using bar = decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()));
```

You can verify that

```
static_assert( std::is_same<bar<my_first_class_t>,
                            my_first_class_inner_types_t>{}, "!" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
template <class Atomics>
struct inner_types;

template <template <class...> class T, class... Atomic>
struct inner_types<T<Atomic...>>
{
    using type = MyclassAcceptingInnerTypes<typename Atomic::inner_type...>;
};


using atomics = MyclassAcceptingAtomicTypes<Atomic1, Atomic2>;
using inners  = MyclassAcceptingInnerTypes<Atomic1::inner_type ,  Atomic2::inner_type >;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<inner_types<atomics>::type, inners>);
```